# Set item on v-select through a button press -> @change is not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button

```
<v-btn
  v-if="getEnviroment"
  @click="fillOther"
>
  fillOther
</v-btn>
```

on the page visible only for local host. A click on this button should select the first element of the v-select.

Setting the item is simple:

```
fillOther () {
  this.inputForm.tsi = 69
}
```

The issue is, that the @change Event is not triggered through this.

**How can i tigger the @change event on the v-select?**

```
<v-select
  id="TsiAuswahl"
  v-model.trim="inputForm.tsi"
  :items="tsiItems"
  label="Leistungsart"
  item-text="anzeigetext"
  item-value="wert"
  data-test="tsi"
  :return-object="false"
  @change="onChangeTSI"
>
  <template
    v-slot:item="{item }"
  >
    <span :id="'tsiSelect_listItem_' + item.id">{{ item.anzeigetext }}</span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Thank you in advance!